# MySQL Stored Procedure Column Name Join Syntax

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm getting all kinds of errors with this stored procedure, from undefined column names to ambiguous field names.

What I'm trying to do is select each subscriber ID where action, share, test, viral, and total are at the highest value.  The subscriberID can will be different for each highest value, so you might be returning up to 5 subscriberIDs.  Maybe my logic is off here, but below is my code(Please note this is just for the 'action' column):

```
  SELECT `set1.subscriber_id`, `set1.action`, `set1.share`, `set1.test`, `set1.viral`, ( `set1.action` + `set1.share` + `set1.test` + `set1.viral` ) AS "total", `abuse_flag`

  FROM `subscribers_points` set1

  JOIN
        (
        SELECT `subscriber_id`, MAX(`action`) AS actionMax
        FROM `subscribers_points`
        WHERE `year` = _year
        AND `month` = _month
        GROUP BY `subscriber_id`
        ) groupedAction

  ON set1.subscriber_id=groupedAction.subscriber_id

  WHERE `year` = _year

  AND `month` = _month;
```

^ This resulted in 'Unknown column 'set1.subscriber_id' in 'field list'

This looks correct to me.  I don't know what's causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this ... without most of the backticks ... you only need the backticks to escape reserved words, etc.

```
SELECT set1.subscriber_id, set1.action, set1.share, set1.test, set1.viral, 
( set1.action + set1.share + set1.test + set1.viral ) AS "total", abuse_flag
FROM subscribers_points set1
JOIN (
    SELECT subscriber_id, MAX(`action`) AS actionMax
    FROM subscribers_points
    WHERE year = _year
    AND month = _month
    GROUP BY subscriber_id
    ) as groupedAction
ON set1.subscriber_id=groupedAction.subscriber_id
WHERE year = _year
AND month = _month;
```

Comment: Thank you, the previous coder liked to use an excessive amount of backticks, I was just trying to replicate that method.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'as' before groupedAction.

```
  SELECT `set1.subscriber_id`, `set1.action`, `set1.share`, `set1.test`, `set1.viral`, ( `set1.action` + `set1.share` + `set1.test` + `set1.viral` ) AS "total", `abuse_flag`

  FROM `subscribers_points` set1

  JOIN
        (
        SELECT `subscriber_id`, MAX(`action`) AS actionMax
        FROM `subscribers_points`
        WHERE `year` = _year
        AND `month` = _month
        GROUP BY `subscriber_id`
        ) as groupedAction

  ON set1.subscriber_id=groupedAction.subscriber_id

  WHERE `year` = _year

  AND `month` = _month;
```